# rsync using part of a relative path

Tags: rsync

Suppose I have a directory on a local machine, behind a firewall:

```
local:/home/meee/workdir/
```

And a directory on a remote machine, on the other side of the firewall:

```
remote:/a1/a2/.../aN/one/two/
remote:/a1/a2/.../aN/one/dont-copy-me{1,2,3,...}/
```

...such that `N` >= 0.

My local machine has a script that uses `rsync`.  I want this script to copy only `one/two/` from the remote machine for a variable-but-known 'N' such that I end up with:

```
local:/home/meee/workdir/one/two/
```

If I use `rsync remote:/a1/a2/.../aN/one/two/ ~/workdir/`, I end up with:

```
local:/home/meee/workdir/two/
```

If I use `rsync --relative remote:/a1/a2/.../aN/one/two/ ~/workdir/`, I end up with:

```
local:/home/meee/workdir/a1/a2/.../aN/one/two/
```

Neither one of these is what I want.

1. Are there `rsync` flags which can achieve the desired result?
2. If not, can anyone think of a straightforward solution?

Comment: create `remote:/a1/a2/.../aN/one/`, then rou can copy _two_ into _one_.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/552120/preserve-directory-tree-while-copying-with-rsync

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For -- relative you have to insert a dot into the source directory path:

```
rsync -av --relative remote:/a1/a2/.../aN/./one/two ~/workdir/
```

See the manual:

> -R, --relative
>
> [...]
>
> It  is  also possible to limit the amount of path information that is sent as implied directories for each path you specify.  With a modern rsync on the sending side (beginning with
>                 2.6.7), you can insert a dot and a slash into the source path, like this:

```
             rsync -avR /foo/./bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are pulling files from an `rsync` older than v2.6.7, you can do this by taking advantage of `rsync`'s `--rsync-path` option, which is meant to allow you to specify where the rsync command can be found on the remote. However, you can use it to change directory first. Simply,

```
rsync -aR --rsync-path='cd /a1/a2/.../aN/ && rsync' remote:one/two/ ~/workdir/
```